# Arraylist exception error

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a beginner in java programming. I am trying to develop a program but when I ran my program which is posted below and it came back with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:635)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
at Instruction.instructionProcess(Instruction.java:27)
at Instruction.main(Instruction.java:79)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is my Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Instruction {

    public static void firstWord(ArrayList<String> optionCode, ArrayList<String> optionCodeList) {
        for (int i = 0; i<optionCode.size(); i++) {
            if (!optionCodeList.contains(optionCode.get(i))) {
                optionCode.set(i,optionCode.get(i).substring(0, optionCode.get(i).indexOf(' ')) + "  *****ERROR*****");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void instructionProcess(ArrayList<String> optionCode) {
        for (int i=0; i<optionCode.size(); i++) {
            if (optionCode.get(i).contains("LD")) {
                if (optionCode.get(i+1).contains("ADD.D")) {
                    optionCode.add(i+1, "stall   -----------");
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<optionCode.size(); i++) {
            if (optionCode.get(i).contains("ADD.D")) {
                if (optionCode.get(i+1).contains("S.D")) {
                    optionCode.add(i+1, "stall   ----------");
                    optionCode.add(i+2, "stall   ----------");
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<optionCode.size(); i++) {
            if (optionCode.get(i).contains("BNEZ")) {
                optionCode.add(i+1, "stall   ----------");
            }
            System.out.println(optionCode.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void printOutput(ArrayList<String> optionCode) {
        for (int i=0; i<optionCode.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(optionCode.get(i).substring(0, optionCode.get(i).indexOf(' ')));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> optionCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        optionCodeList.add("LD");
        optionCodeList.add("SD");
        optionCodeList.add("ADD.D");
        optionCodeList.add("SUB.D");
        optionCodeList.add("MUL.D");
        optionCodeList.add("DIV.D");
        optionCodeList.add("SUBI");
        optionCodeList.add("SUB");
        optionCodeList.add("ADDI");
        optionCodeList.add("ADD");
        optionCodeList.add("BNEZ");
        optionCodeList.add("BEZ");
        optionCodeList.add("BRA");

        Scanner File = new Scanner(new File("in_sample.txt"));
        while (File.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = File.nextLine();
            ArrayList<String> optionCode = new ArrayList<>();
            Scanner text = new Scanner(line);
            while (text.hasNextLine()) {
                optionCode.add(text.nextLine());
            }
            firstWord(optionCode, optionCodeList);
            instructionProcess(optionCode);
            printOutput(optionCode);

            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Output.txt");
            for (int i = 0; i < optionCode.size(); i++) {
                outFile.println(optionCode.get(i));
            }
            outFile.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at nested `if`. In case you hit the end element and it satisfies `contains` condition, you will try to access `i+1` element which is out of range.

Comment: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1`: The exception is pretty clear. You are trying to access position `1` of an `ArrayList` which has size `1`, so the only available index is `0`.

Comment: You even have line numbers, so you can see exactly which line of code is causing this exception.

Comment: Also, you have three individual that iterate in the exact same manner. As none of them seem dependent on the previous ones modifying the array, those iterations are really redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general look on that lines

```
 for (int i=0; i<optionCode.size(); i++) {
            if (optionCode.get(i).contains("LD")) {
                if (optionCode.get(i+1).contains("ADD.D")) { // from there you got an exception
                    optionCode.add(i+1, "stall   -----------");
```

If you would like to get sth from the next element on the list that isn't the elemtent that you current iterates on you have to put weaker condition in `loop` simply:

```
 for (int i=0; i<optionCode.size()-1; i++) {
            if (optionCode.get(i).contains("LD")) {
                if (optionCode.get(i+1).contains("ADD.D")) { //now you have sure that i+1 will return sth not null.
                    optionCode.add(i+1, "stall   -----------");
//now you have sure that i+1 will return sth not null.
```

Please replace your `loop` condition in every loop that you try to get sth `i+1` because it will cause exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
for (int i=0; i<optionCode.size(); i++) {
            if (optionCode.get(i).contains("ADD.D")) {
                if (optionCode.get(i+1).contains("S.D")) {
                    optionCode.add(i+1, "stall   ----------");
                    optionCode.add(i+2, "stall   ----------");
                }
            }
        }
```

In here when i is maximum optionCode.get(i+1) won't work..
you have to apply exceptions on that scenario..